# AngularJS: late-binding of ng-model to dom element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding

I have a web page with some HTML elements which I cannot edit. I'd like to dynamically attach ng-model attributes to these and have AngularJS re-bind them to the scope. A simplified example of what I want to accomplish can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/axedre/E2h9t/1/)

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.myModel1 = "Hi";
    $scope.myModel2 = "there";
    var myModel2 = angular.element("#myModel2");
    //This won't work
    myModel2.attr("ng-model", "myModel2");
}
</script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="myModel1"/>
    <!-- I can't touch this -->
    <input type="text" id="myModel2" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 14):

You need to use `$compile` ([docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile))

```
$compile(myModel2.attr("ng-model", "myModel2"))($scope);
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XPh96/)

When you load your page, angular uses `$compile` on the HTML automatically, that's how it knows which elements to assign which directives to. If you just change the attribute like you tried, angular doesn't know. You have to use `$compile`.

Comment: Sorry but I don't have enough reputation points to accept your answer; I will come back to it when I do!

Comment: Thanks Mosho. Here'a s snippet how to do a late binding of ng-model to select: <select id="timezone"></select> $compile(angular.element('#timezone'),
angular.element('#timezone').attr('ng-model', 'vm.timeZone'))($scope);